# Adding UILabel as subview of UIImageView hiding image view image

Tags: uiimageview, uilabel

```
UIImageView *newView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 15.0f, 15.0f)];
    [newView setImage:image];

    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 15.0f, 15.0f)];
    newLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    newLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
    newLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    newLabel.text = labelText;
    newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [newView addSubview:newLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added two new line in your code and modified one line,i hope it helps you..

```
UIImageView *newView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 150.0f)];
[newView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];//Modified line
[self.view addSubview:newView];//New added line

UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 150.0f)];
newLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
newLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
newLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
newLabel.text = @"labelText";
newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[newView addSubview:newLabel];
```

if your newLabel text is long you can add this..

```
newLabel.numberOfLines = 3;//New added line
```